# Listing all related objects and allow paging on related objects

Tags: django

Can someone give me the best approach with an example for the following...

On a page I load the '**Group**' object by ID. I also want to list all contacts that belong to that group (with paging).

Because of the paging issue I was thinking of just running a second database query with...

In my view...

```
group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk=id)
contacts = Contacts.objects.filter(group=x)
```

But this seems wasteful as I'm already getting the Group why hit the database twice.

See my model.

```
class GroupManager(models.Manager):

    def for_user(self, user):
        return self.get_query_set().filter(user=user,)


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True, auto_now=True,)

    #FK
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user")

    objects = GroupManager()


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('contacts.views.group', args=[str(self.id)])


class Contact(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    #FK
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

Comment: Please post the view where the query is taking place in addition to your models (which you already posted).

Comment: I have updated the question with how I'm thinking of doing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) is designed for:

> Returns a QuerySet that will automatically “follow” foreign-key
>   relationships, selecting that additional related-object data when it
>   executes its query. This is a performance booster which results in
>   (sometimes much) larger queries but means later use of foreign-key
>   relationships won’t require database queries.

In your case it would be:

```
Group.objects.select_related().get(pk=group)
```

Now on each FK lookup, you won't hit the database again.

The next step would be to cache the results using the [cache api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api) so that you don't hit the database everytime the next "page" is called. This would be useful if your data isn't time sensitive.